# <identifier> expected error.Not able to resolve it

Tags: java, jar, compilation, compiler-errors

Following is the code the has two classses FieldMap and Xfrmr_new
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
package javax.xml.xpath;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Set;
import java.lang.Object;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.jdom2.Attribute;
import org.jdom2.Document;
import org.jdom2.Element;
import org.jdom2.JDOMException;
import org.jdom2.Text;
import org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder;
import org.jdom2.xpath.*;
import org.jdom2.*;
import org.jdom2.filter.*;
import org.jdom2.xpath;




 class FieldMap 
  {

            private String xpath;
        private XPathExpression<Object> xPathExp;

        public FieldMap()
        {
          setXpathRoot();
          setXpathData();
        }

        public String getXpath() 
        {
          return xpath;
        }

        public String getLeafName()
        {
          if (xpath != null && xpath.isEmpty() == false)
              {
                return xpath.substring(xpath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1,xpath.length());
              } else return null;
        }



         public void setXpath(String xpath)
             {
               this.xpath = xpath;              
               xPathExp = XPathFactory.instance().compile(xpath);

             }

        public void setXpath (String xpath, Integer collectionCount)
             {
                 this.xpath = xpath;    
                 if (collectionCount > 0 && xpath != null && xpath.isEmpty() == false && xpath.contains("/"))
              {         
                 xpath = xpath.substring(0, xpath.lastIndexOf("/"));
              }
                 xPathExp = XPathFactory.instance().compile(xpath);     
             }


    public XPathExpression<Object> getXpathExp()
       {
        return xPathExp;
       }

    private ValueType valueType;

    public ValueType getValueType() 
       {
        return valueType;
        }

    public void setValueType(ValueType valueType)
      {
        this.valueType = valueType;
      }

    private String dataType;

    public String getDataType() 
    {
        return dataType;
    }

    public void setDataType(String dataType) 
    {
        this.dataType = dataType;
    }

    private String format;

    public String getFormat() {
        return format;
    }

    public void setFormat(String format) {
        this.format = format;
    }

    private int collectionCount;

    public int getCollectionCount() {
        return collectionCount;
    }

    public void setCollectionCount(int collectionCount) {
        this.collectionCount = collectionCount;
    }

    private String outputName;

    public String getOutputName() {
        return outputName;
    }

    public void setOutputName(String outputName) {
        this.outputName = outputName;
    }

    private String delimiter;

    public String getDelimiter() {
        return delimiter;
    }

    public void setDelimiter(String delimiter) {
        this.delimiter = delimiter;
    }


    private String xpathNormalize;

    public String getXpathNormalize() {
        return xpath;
    }


    private XPathExpression<Element> xPathExpNormalize;

    public void setXpathNormalize (String xpath) {      
        xPathExpNormalize = XPathFactory.instance().compile(xpath,Filters.element());   
    }
    public XPathExpression<Element> getXpathExpToNormalize (){
        return xPathExpNormalize;
    }

    private XPathExpression<Document> xPathExpRoot;

    private void setXpathRoot ()
    {       
        xPathExpRoot = XPathFactory.instance().compile("/",Filters.document());
        System.out.println("Inside setXpathExpRoot"+xPathExpRoot);
    }

    public XPathExpression<Document> getXpathRoot()
    {
        return xPathExpRoot;
    }

    private XPathExpression<Document> xPathExpData;

    private void setXpathData() 
    {       
        xPathExpData= XPathFactory.instance().compile("/",Filters.document());
        System.out.println("Inside setXpathData"+xPathExpData);
    }

    public XPathExpression<Document> getXpathData()
    {
        return xPathExpData;
    }

    public enum ValueType
    {
        String, NUMERIC
    }



    private String outputData;

    public String getOutputData()
    {
        return outputData;
    }

    public void setOutputData(String outputData)
    {
        this.outputData = outputData;
    }


    //private XPathExpression<Element> xPathExp;
        private XPathExpression<Object> xPathNew;
        private String xpathdata;

        /*public void setXpathData (String xpathdata) {
            this.xpathdata = xpathdata;             
            xPathNew = XPathFactory.instance().compile(xpathdata);

        }*/

        public void setXpathData (String xpathdata, Integer collectionCount)
       {
            this.xpathdata = xpathdata; 
            if (collectionCount > 0 && xpathdata != null 
                    && xpathdata.isEmpty() == false
                    && xpathdata.contains("/")) 
           {

                /*in the case where we want to create different columns for the same field name
                 * this sets the xpath to the parent of the leaf
                 *it is intended to keep the order           
                 */         
                xpathdata = xpathdata.substring(0, xpathdata.lastIndexOf("/"));
            }
            xPathNew = XPathFactory.instance().compile(xpathdata);      
        }


        public XPathExpression<Object> getXpathNew()
        {
            return xPathNew;
        }

        public String getLeafNameNew()
        {
            if (xpathdata != null && xpathdata.isEmpty() == false)
            {
                return xpathdata.substring(xpathdata.lastIndexOf("/") + 1,xpathdata.length());
            } else 
               {
                 return null;
               }
        }

}



public class Xfrmr_new 
{
    private static String ELEMENT = "ELEMENT";
    private static String ATTRIBUTE = "ATTRIBUTE";
    private static String STRING = "STRING";
    private static String TEXT = "TEXT";
    private static String DOUBLE = "DOUBLE";
    private static String BOOLEAN = "BOOLEAN";
    private static List<FieldMap> fields;
    // Create a hash map
    public static HashMap<String,String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
    public static HashMap<String,String> hmn = new HashMap<String,String>();



    public Xfrmr_new(List<FieldMap> fields){
        Xfrmr_new.fields = fields;
    }


    public static String transform(byte[] payload){

        try {

            SAXBuilder sax = new SAXBuilder();
            Document doc = sax.build(new ByteArrayInputStream(payload));            
            return transform(doc);


        } catch (Exception e){
            return null;
        }

    }

    public  static String transform(Document xmldoc)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
        List<String> escapes = new ArrayList<String>();
        escapes.add("\n");      
        escapes.add(fields.get(0).getDelimiter());

        if (fields.get(0).getXpathExpToNormalize() == null)
        {
            //single row per pcn
            Document root = fields.get(0).getXpathRoot().evaluateFirst(xmldoc);         
            sb.append(transformOneRow(root.getRootElement(),escapes));

        } else
        {
            //System.out.println("Inside Normalize On");
            //multiple rows per pcn
            List<Element> elements = fields.get(0).getXpathExpToNormalize().evaluate(xmldoc);           
            for (Element element : elements)
            {               
                sb.append(transformOneRow(element,escapes));
                //sb.append("\t1"); //add a tab and 1 to match context.write
                sb.append( System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                //System.out.println("inside norm"+sb);
            }   
            //get rid of the last tab,1,& newline
            if (sb.length()>0)
            {
                //int newLineSize = System.getProperty("line.separator").length();
                //sb.replace(sb.length()-(2+newLineSize),sb.length(),"");
            }
         }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public  static String transformOneRow(Element element,List<String> escapes)      
      {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
        String nameValue="";;
        String dataValue="";
        int pswFlag = 0;
        int deltaFlag = 0;
        int expFlag = 0;
        int teltrkFlag = 0;
        int sbdFlag = 0;
        int digFlag = 0;
        int hmFlag = 0;
        int hvdFlag = 0;
        for (FieldMap f : fields)
        {
         if (f.getCollectionCount() <= 0)
            {
                try 
                  {             
                    Object obj = f.getXpathExp().evaluateFirst(element);
                    List<Object> objs = f.getXpathExp().evaluate(element);
                    Element prnts = (Element)objs.get(0);
                    //System.out.println("prints print check"+getValue(prnts.getChild(f.getLeafName()),escapes));
                    System.out.println("prints check"+prnts.getValue());

                    if(prnts.getValue().equals("PSW01") && f.getOutputName().equals("Suite_id")){
                        pswFlag = 1;
                        System.out.println("inside psw01 if");
                    }
                    if(prnts.getValue().equals("DELTA01") && f.getOutputName().equals("Suite_id")){
                        deltaFlag = 1;
                        System.out.println("inside Delta01 if");
                    }               
                    if(prnts.getValue().equals("EXP01") && f.getOutputName().equals("Suite_id")){
                            expFlag = 1;
                            System.out.println("inside exp01 if");
                    }
                    System.out.println("expFlag in first loop"+expFlag);
                    if(prnts.getValue().equals("TELTRK01") && f.getOutputName().equals("Suite_id")){
                        teltrkFlag = 1;
                        System.out.println("inside Teltrk01 if");
                    }
                    if(prnts.getValue().equals("SBD0001") && f.getOutputName().equals("Suite_id")){
                        sbdFlag = 1;
                        System.out.println("inside sbd0001 if");
                    }
                    if(prnts.getValue().equals("DIGITAL") && f.getOutputName().equals("Suite_id")){
                        digFlag = 1;
                        System.out.println("inside Digital if");
                    }
                    if(prnts.getValue().equals("HVD0001") && f.getOutputName().equals("Suite_id")){
                        hvdFlag = 1;
                        System.out.println("inside HVD0001 if");
                    }                   
                    sb.append(getValue(obj,escapes));
                    sb.append(f.getDelimiter());
                    //System.out.println("Fields outputname without CC:- "+f.getOutputName());
                    //System.out.println("NO CC objects:"+obj);
                    //System.out.println("NO CC SB:"+sb);


                } catch (Exception e){
                    sb.append(f.getDelimiter());
                }   

            }   

            else
            {               
                    System.out.println("inside else coll count>0");
                    int ctr = 0;

                    List<Object> objects = f.getXpathExp().evaluate(element);
                    List<Object> objectsNew = f.getXpathNew().evaluate(element);
                    //String occurrances[] = new String[f.getCollectionCount()];

                    //System.out.println("obj size :-"+objects.size());
                    //System.out.println("obj new size :-"+objectsNew.size());
                    for (ctr=0 ;ctr<f.getCollectionCount();ctr++){

                        try
                          {
                            /*if (objects.size() >= ctr){*/
                            if (10 >= ctr){
                                Element prnt = (Element)objects.get(ctr);
                                nameValue = getValue(prnt.getChild(f.getLeafName()),escapes);
                                System.out.println("else part nameValue"+nameValue);
                                System.out.println("get output name"+f.getOutputName());
                                System.out.println("exp flag"+expFlag);
                                //if(expFlag==1 && getValue(prnt.getChild(f.getLeafName()),escapes).equals("SSN-UNIQ-IND-1") &&

                                if(pswFlag==1 && nameValue.equals("SW-ADR-MATCH-IND-1") && f.getOutputName().equals("TagName") ){
                                    System.out.println("inside SW-ADR-MATCH-IND-1 if");
                                    hm.put(nameValue,"");
                                }
                                if(pswFlag==1 && nameValue.equals("SW-AMT-BL-XFR-1") && f.getOutputName().equals("TagName") ){
                                    System.out.println("inside SW-AMT-BL-XFR-1 if");
                                    hm.put(nameValue,"");
                                }
                                if(pswFlag==1 && nameValue.equals("SW-AMT-BL-XFR12M-1") && f.getOutputName().equals("TagName") ){
                                    System.out.println("inside SW-AMT-BL-XFR12M-1 if");
                                    hm.put(nameValue,"");
                                }

                                if(pswFlag==1 && nameValue.equals("SW-AV-PAY-3M-1") && f.getOutputName().equals("TagName")){hm.put(nameValue,"");}
                                if(hvdFlag==1 && nameValue.equals("SOW-PRNT-1-NETWRTH-1") && f.getOutputName().equals("TagName")){hm.put(nameValue,"");}
                                if(hvdFlag==1 && nameValue.equals("SOW-PRNT-2-NETWRTH-1") && f.getOutputName().equals("TagName")){hm.put(nameValue,"");}
                                if(hvdFlag==1 && nameValue.equals("SOW-COLL-TIER-1") && f.getOutputName().equals("TagName")){hm.put(nameValue,"");}
                                if(hvdFlag==1 && nameValue.equals("HVD-INCOME-360-1") && f.getOutputName().equals("TagName")){hm.put(nameValue,"");}

                                System.out.println("hm flag"+hmFlag);
                                sb.append(getValue(prnt.getChild(f.getLeafName()),escapes));
                                sb.append(f.getDelimiter());
                                //System.out.println("getchild output :-"+prnt.getChild(f.getLeafName()));
                                //System.out.println("getleafname output :-"+ f.getLeafName());
                                //System.out.println("Fields outputname with CC :- "+f.getOutputName());
                                System.out.println("getvalue output :-"+getValue(prnt.getChild(f.getLeafName()),escapes));
                                //System.out.println("inside if:"+sb);
                            }
                        }catch (Exception e){
                            sb.append(f.getDelimiter());
                            //System.out.println("inside catch1");
                            //e.printStackTrace();

                        }

                        try{


                            /*if (objectsNew.size() >= ctr){*/
                                if (10 >= ctr){
                                Element prntNew = (Element)objectsNew.get(ctr);
                                //System.out.println("prntNew :"+prntNew);
                                dataValue = getValue(prntNew.getChild(f.getLeafNameNew()),escapes);
                                Object v = hm.get(nameValue);
                                if (v != null){
                                    hmn.put(nameValue,dataValue); 
                                }
                                sb.append(getValue(prntNew.getChild(f.getLeafNameNew()),escapes));
                                sb.append(f.getDelimiter());
                                //System.out.println("inside xpathNew sb : "+sb);
                                //System.out.println("getchild output second:-"+prntNew.getChild(f.getLeafNameNew()));
                                //System.out.println("getleafname output second :-"+ f.getLeafNameNew());
                                //System.out.println("Fields outputname with CC second :- "+f.getOutputData());
                                //System.out.println("getvalue output second :-"+getValue(prntNew.getChild(f.getLeafNameNew()),escapes));
                                //System.out.println("inside if:"+sb);
                            }
                        }catch (Exception e){
                            sb.append(f.getDelimiter());
                            //System.out.println("inside catch2");
                            //e.printStackTrace();

                        }

                    }
                    //System.out.println("CC objects:"+objects);
                    //System.out.println("CC SB:"+sb);
                      // Get a set of the entries
                      Set<Entry<String, String>> set = hm.entrySet();
                      // Get an iterator
                      Iterator<Entry<String, String>> i = set.iterator();
                      // Display elements
                      while(i.hasNext()) {
                         Map.Entry me = i.next();
                         System.out.print("key : " + me.getKey() + ": ");
                         System.out.println("value : " + me.getValue());
                      }

                      /*Set<Entry<String, String>> setn = hmn.entrySet();
                      Iterator<Entry<String, String>> in = setn.iterator();
                      while(in.hasNext()) {
                         Map.Entry men = in.next();
                         System.out.print("key : " + men.getKey() + ": ");
                         System.out.println("value : " + men.getValue());
                      }*/
            }           
        }       
        return sb.toString();       
    }

    private static String getValue(Object obj, List<String> escapes){
        if (obj == null) {
            return "";
        }
        String type = obj.getClass().toString();
        type = type.substring(type.lastIndexOf(".")+1,type.length());

        if (type.toUpperCase().equals(ELEMENT)) {
            Element element = (Element)obj;
            if (element.getTextTrim() != null) {
                return CleanUp(element.getTextTrim(),escapes);                              
            }                       
        }else if (type.toUpperCase().equals(ATTRIBUTE)) {
            Attribute attribute = (Attribute)obj;
            if (attribute.getValue() != null) {
                return CleanUp(attribute.getValue(),escapes);                           
            }                                           
        }else if (type.toUpperCase().equals(STRING)) {
            return CleanUp(obj.toString(),escapes); 
        }else if (type.toUpperCase().equals(TEXT)) {
            Text text = (Text)obj;
            return CleanUp(text.getText(),escapes);
        }else if (type.toUpperCase().equals(DOUBLE)) {
            return CleanUp(obj.toString(),escapes);
        }else if (type.toUpperCase().equals(BOOLEAN)) {
            return CleanUp(obj.toString(),escapes);
        }else {
            return null;
        }
        return "";  
    }

    private static String CleanUp(String value, List<String> listToReplace){

        for (String replace : listToReplace){
            value = value.replace(replace, " ");
        }
        return value;
    }

    public static String Header(){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");

        for (FieldMap field : fields){
            if(field.getCollectionCount() > 0) {
                for (int i=0; i<field.getCollectionCount();i++){
                    sb.append(field.getOutputName() + "_" + i);
                    sb.append(field.getDelimiter());
                    sb.append(field.getOutputData() + "_" + i);
                    sb.append(field.getDelimiter());
                }               
            }
            else {
                sb.append(field.getOutputName() + field.getDelimiter());
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }


    public static List<FieldMap> GetXfrmDetails(String mappingFile) {
        List<FieldMap> fields = new ArrayList<FieldMap>();
        SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
        File xmlFile = new File(mappingFile);

        try {

            Document document = (Document) builder.build(xmlFile);
            Element rootNode = document.getRootElement();
            List<Element> list = rootNode.getChildren("Table");

            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

                Element node = list.get(i);
                FieldMap field = new FieldMap();

                String childVal;
                childVal = node.getChildTextTrim("collectionCount");
                if (childVal != null && childVal.isEmpty() == false) {
                    field.setCollectionCount(Integer.parseInt(childVal));
                }

                field.setDataType(node.getChildTextTrim("DataType"));
                field.setFormat(node.getChildTextTrim("formatString"));
                field.setOutputName(node.getChildTextTrim("outputName"));
                field.setOutputData(node.getChildTextTrim("outputData"));
                childVal = node.getChildTextTrim("DataType");
                if (childVal.equals("NUMERIC")) {
                    field.setValueType(FieldMap.ValueType.NUMERIC);
                } else {
                    field.setValueType(FieldMap.ValueType.String);
                }       

                //System.out.println("collec count"+field.getCollectionCount());
                if (field.getCollectionCount() > 0 ) {
                    field.setXpath(node.getChildTextTrim("xPath"), field. getCollectionCount());    
                    //System.out.println("CC xpathdata"+node.getChildTextTrim("xPathData"));
                    field.setXpathData(node.getChildTextTrim("xPathData"),field. getCollectionCount());
                }else {
                    field.setXpath(node.getChildTextTrim("xPath"));
                }

                field.setDelimiter(node.getChildTextTrim("ReportDelimiter"));
                if (node.getChildTextTrim("xPathToNormalizeOn") != null) {
                    field.setXpathNormalize(node.getChildTextTrim("xPathToNormalizeOn"));
                }

                fields.add(field);

            }

        } catch (IOException io) {
            System.out.println("error in io");
            System.out.println(io.getMessage());
        } catch (JDOMException jdomex) {
            System.out.println("error in jdom");
            System.out.println(jdomex.getMessage());
        } /*catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error message");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }*/

        return fields;
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {

        List<FieldMap> fields;
        Xfrmr_new xfrm;
        fields = Xfrmr_new.GetXfrmDetails("/mdl/us4/quetool/QUEDATA/OPEN_XML/SBE_Inquiry/input/SBEInquiry.xml");
        File directory = new File("/mdl/us4/quetool/QUEDATA/OPEN_XML/SBE_Inquiry/inquiry_pcn");
        System.out.println("looking for input files in " + directory.getAbsolutePath());
        File[] files = directory.listFiles();
        File ofile = new File("/mdl/us4/quetool/QUEDATA/OPEN_XML/SBE_Inquiry/output/inquiry_output.csv");
        FileOutputStream fop = new FileOutputStream(ofile);
        int count=0;
        for(File file : files ){
            byte[] xml;
            xml = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);

            xfrm = new Xfrmr_new(fields);

            // if file doesnt exists, then create it
            if (!ofile.exists()) {
                ofile.createNewFile();
            }
            //add the header record
            if (count==0){
                fop.write((Xfrmr_new.Header() + System.getProperty("line.separator")).getBytes());
                count++;
            }
            fop.write((Xfrmr_new.transform(xml)).getBytes());
            fop.write((System.getProperty("line.separator")).getBytes());

            }
         Set<Entry<String, String>> setn = hmn.entrySet();
          // Get an iterator
          Iterator<Entry<String, String>> in = setn.iterator();
          // Display elements
          while(in.hasNext()) {
             Map.Entry men = in.next();
             System.out.print("final key : " + men.getKey() + ": ");
             System.out.println("final value : " + men.getValue());
          }
        System.out.println("Its done!! :)");
    }
}
```

---

I am getting the following errors when i run the code

```
Xfrmr_new.java:51: <identifier> expected
        private XPathExpression<Object> xPathExp;
                               ^
Xfrmr_new.java:92: <identifier> expected
        public XPathExpression<Object> getXpathExp()
                              ^
Xfrmr_new.java:169: <identifier> expected
        private XPathExpression<Element> xPathExpNormalize;
                               ^
Xfrmr_new.java:174: <identifier> expected
        public XPathExpression<Element> getXpathExpToNormalize (){
                              ^
Xfrmr_new.java:186: <identifier> expected
        public XPathExpression<Document> getXpathRoot()
                              ^
Xfrmr_new.java:199: <identifier> expected
        public XPathExpression<Document> getXpathData()
                              ^
Xfrmr_new.java:225: <identifier> expected
                private XPathExpression<Object> xPathNew;
                                       ^
Xfrmr_new.java:252: <identifier> expected
                public XPathExpression<Object> getXpathNew()
                                      ^
Xfrmr_new.java:267: ';' expected

^
Xfrmr_new.java:280: <identifier> expected
        private static List<FieldMap> fields;
                           ^
Xfrmr_new.java:282: <identifier> expected
    public static HashMap<String,String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
                         ^
Xfrmr_new.java:283: <identifier> expected
    public static HashMap<String,String> hmn = new HashMap<String,String>();
                         ^
Xfrmr_new.java:287: <identifier> expected
        public Xfrmr_new(List<FieldMap> fields){
                             ^
Xfrmr_new.java:878: ')' expected
}
^
14 errors
```

---

I added the following jars in my classpath

```
commons-cli-1.2.jar
commons-compress-1.2.jar
commons-io-2.4.jar
hadoop-common-0.21.0.jar
java-rt-jar-stubs-1.5.0.jar
jaxen-1.1.2.jar
jdom-2.0.4.jar
jdom-2.0.4-contrib.jar
jgoodies-common-1.1.1.jar
jgoodies-forms-1.4.1.jar
```

---

Comment: You need to compile this using Java 1.5 setting or higher to allow you to use generics.

Comment: Which version of Java are you compiling this as?

Comment: The version is 1.6.0_65

Comment: @sweetpoison: you may be assuming incorrectly. You may be using a Java 1.6 compiler but your setting looks to be 1.4. If you're using Eclipse then you have to change your Java compiler settings.

Comment: I am compiling this on Unix.The funny thing is that The same code is running on Eclipse perfectly but on Unix it is showing  errors.The command for compilation is javac -classpath "jarfile1 location:jarfile2 location" Xfrmr_new.java

Comment: Check what javac says about -version. This may be standard delivery 1.4

Comment: >java -version
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b32)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 20.65-b04, mixed mode)

Comment: Which what tool (maven?) are you compiling (and not running ;)) when not using Eclipse ? And have you a compile error with StringBuilder ? (which is Java 5).

Comment: I am compiling it on Unix where it is giving the <identifier> expected error. On Eclipse it is working fine where maven 2.2.1 is being used.No there is no compile error WITH StringBuilder

Comment: Its a single java application.I think there is no role of Maven here when i run it on Eclipse

Comment: Not java, `javac -version` - what is displayed by that?

Comment: Weird is, that you try to add a generic parameter to `javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression` in the first place - this interface doesn't have a generic parameter, and you should get an error message saying just that.

Comment: It is bad practice to put anything in a package that's in use by the JDK API - even if it "only" a javax subpackage. You never know what else kĺurks in those packages.

Comment: @NoDataFound Being or not being able to "compile" `StringBuilder` is not conclusive as this merely requires a jar (or class) file containing that class in your class path.

Comment: It was to exclude usage of pre 1.5 JDK. Your answer seems fine to me, he is probably shadowing a JDK class or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Using jdk1.8.0_20. --- This causes an error:

```
import org.jdom2.xpath;
```

Removed. --- Then, I get lots of errors

```
javax/xml/xpath/FieldMap.java:27: error: type XPathExpression does not take parameters
 private XPathExpression<Object> xPathExp;
```

Moving the file from javax.xml.xpath`into a "sane" package removes *all* of those errors, and the file compiles.

That package contains javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression, and this is in conflict with 
`org.jdom2.xpath.XPathExpression`.

I don't know what exactly OP has done to get the posted errors - I still think that it's been compiled using some pre-Tiger java. But the findings concerning the package mishap are worth posting.